# Prevent browser from transforming malformed ulrs

Tags: html

If for example I have

```
<a href="http://1234">Link</a>
```

Looks like : [Link](http://1234)
When I hover mouse on it I see 0.0.4.210 in the bottom of window.
And if I click on it I will get to 0.0.4.210.

I know that such links make no sense, but still if it is possible to change this behavior?
I mean I want to see 1234 and go to 1234 if I click on link.

Comment: Which OS, browser and browser version do you use?

Comment: lets say windows-7 IE/chrome, but I wonder if I can do smth using html/js/... not installing plugins or similar.

Comment: If you are the owner of the website, you can check links using regular expression on the server side. If you are just visitor of the site, I don't think there is a solution, because in this case you had to edit the markup of possibly each website. A solution would be to write a browser plugin, which removed malformed links. (Firefox links to http://1234, not to the calculated IP address)

Comment: Browser converts that number into a IP address.